# Linux command line bugzilla interface

Tags: bugzilla

About 6 months ago I wrote a simple set of bash scripts to generate hourly software project bugzilla reports.  I lost the RAID controller on my development server and only have backups of the scripts I wrote.

The scripts depended on a bugzilla command line interface tool that I can no longer find.

From the format of the command line, the bugzilla tool command structure was:

```
bugzilla search --product $string1 --version $string2
```

Asking if anyone can point me to the tool I was using, searched online but unable to find it.

Comment: You searched online but can't find it? Are you kidding me? Google "bugzilla cli", second and third hit; or "bugzilla command line", second hit: https://github.com/frasertweedale/bugzillatools, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bugzillatools/0.5.3.1.

Comment: Sorry, actually in China and have very problematic access to google.  Tried "bugzilla command line interface" into git w/o any luck.  Thank you for your quick response.